# How to undo a merge between two feature branches?

Tags: git, merge

OK, here is the situation: Two of my colleagues worked on two new features (`feature_1` and `feature_2`). Now there were some changes in one branch `feature_1`, the other developer want to see in his branch `feature_2`. So he merged the branch `feature_1` into his branch `feature_2`. It can be illustrated as so:

Before the merge:

```
P--o--o--o    master
\\     
 \\B--C--D    feature_1
  \
   \A--E      feature_2
```

After the merge:

```
P--o--o--o    master
\\     
 \\B--C--D    feature_1
  \       \
   \A--E---M  feature_2
```

He pushes the merge commit and both developers are going to continue working on their branches.

```
P--o--o--o--o--o--o    master
\\     
 \\B--C--D--o--o--o    feature_1
  \       \
   \A--E---M---o--o    feature_2
```

Now it's time to merge `feature_2` back into master. But if we would just do that, all changes from `feature_1` (at least those from the last merge from `feature_1` into `feature_2`) would be merged back into master. But as `feature_1` is not ready yet, that should not happen.

So how can we "unmerge" `feature_1` from `feature_2`, so the commits from feature_1 will not be merged into master.

I tried to do a `git rebase master` on `feature_2`, but this would only remove the merge commit M, but leave the commits B, C and D (or more precice B', C' and D') on `feature_2`.

Any ideas on how to get the commits from `feature_1` out of `feature_2`? We wouldn't mind to rebase and force push or create a new branch with only the commits from `feature_2`.

**UPDATE (my solution):**

Thanks to @kan, who provided a nice solution for my merge issue. In the comments we also discussed, how to solve it, when multiple merges from `feature_1` to `feature_2` happend. I have found a solutions in a single command, that would to the trick. So let's assume, we have the following scenario:

```
P--o--o--o--o--o--o--o    master
\\     
 \\B--C--D--o--o--o--o    feature_1
  \       \     \
   \A--E---M--o--M2--o    feature_2
```

So we have merged twice. No a rebase also have to be done twice. The first one -with `--onto M2^ M2` and the second one with `--onto M^ M`. This can be done with this single command:

`git rev-list --ancestry-path master..HEAD --merges | xargs -I % git rebase --onto %^ % feature_2`

This will basically get all the merge commits from the range `master` to the `HEAD` of `feature_2` two and runs the rebase on "from right to left". So it will first use M2 and than M in the rebase. This command can also be used, if there is only one merge commit, but than you can simply use the shorter `git rebase --onto M^ M` command.

Comment: Does **any** of the work done in `feature_2` depend on **any** of the work in `feature_1`?

Comment: Not really. Both implement new features on two different parts of the project. The only reason, he merged `feature_1` into `feature_2` was to see both changes together. We are now using an integration branch (something like `feature_1and2`) where we just merge both in, but don't work on it. So every commit from `feature_1` can be savely be removed from `feature_2`.

Comment: If you have a solution as well, feel encouraged to post it as an answer.  Adding it to your question would confuse others as to trying to ascertain what was part of your question and what was part of an attempted solution.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I changed the headline to make clear, that the update is about a solution. Or should I really post it as an answer. It is a valid solution, but for a more complex scenario than described in my initial question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most visible way to do it - do `rebase -i` and manually drop feature_1's commits. If there are too many commits to filter manually, let me know, I'll try think harder...

Ok. Thinking harder... ;)

I suggest, there is only one merge point M. In this case you should rebase all commits after merge commit onto the commit right before merge point. Use `git rebase --onto E M feature_2`.

Comment: How about 234 commits on `feature_1` all with pretty bad commit messages? :)

Comment: I don't quite get, which commit is M2 in my example, is it the right one od this three: `E---M---o`, so the `o` commit?

Comment: @2ndkauboy correct. In other words: move all commits right after the merge onto the commit right before the merge.

Comment: Great! That really works. So what is this `onto` exactly does with two commits given? How would it be, if there is no M2. Would it than only be `git rebase --onto E`? The only rebase I ever did was something like `git rebase [-i] master` but that would have lead to the situation shown above.

Comment: Oh, I just realised, that it hasn't worked correctly. Now commit M2 is missing. I mean I could cherry-pick it on top of the rebased branch, but is there another way to keep it? There might have been more than one commit after M.

Comment: @2ndkauboy Oh... It is typical "off-by-one" error :) You should use just "M", not "M2" :) Fixing the answer...

Comment: @2ndkauboy "--onto" specifies exact base for the rebase operation. The two arguments specify a range of commits which should be rebased. Open the "git help rebase" it shows pretty pictures to illustrate the idea.

Comment: OK, that really worked quite well! I now would have a rebased branch with a clean history of only commits originally commited to branch `feature_2`. Would this also work, if I have merged `feature_1` multiple times into `feature_2`?

Comment: @2ndkauboy As git doesn't track information about branches anywhere in commits, it would be more difficult, as in common case it could be quite convoluted history. One way to find out each merge point and do the similar rebase command for each of them. But maybe easier thing to do: you could do something like this: `git rev-list feature_1..feature_2` shows all commits which are in feature_2 but not in feature_1, giving you clean list of changes. Then just do mass `git cherry-pick` for all of them.

Comment: BTW: couldn't it just be `git rebase --onto M^ M` making it easier to find the commit before the merge commit? But with E it would still work.

Comment: Hey @ken, check out my command with `rev-list`. In my test repo, it looks like it is working quite well.

Comment: @2ndkauboy Yes, "M^" is exactly the same, and yes, more 'gitty' way. I just tried to explain using as much stuff as possible. Your command looks cool, when I though about doing something similar, I was thinking to do multiple rebases, but in direct order which will not work. Your command does it in reverse order - good idea. BTW, I am kan, not ken ;)

Comment: Sorry that I misspelled your name. And thanks again for your help. I am slowly getting myself familiar with the advanced git use cases. I think I am going to blog about my issue ad I think I might happen quite often. Although I haven't found a solution for that before.

Answer (score 2):

Since this particular merge has been pushed, you are going to want to [**revert** the merge commit](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-revert).

```
git revert -m 1 <SHA-of-M>
```

Should you want to reintroduce any of the changes from `feature_1` again, you will have to **revert the revert**, but this is the safest option, as it preserves the history of your commits.

To clarify a bit on "revert the revert":  suppose that you've merged this branch to master.

```
P--o--o--o--o--o--o---F2 master
\\                    /
 \\B--C--D--o--o--o  /   feature_1
  \       \         /
   \A--E---M---o--R/     feature_2
```

If you want to merge `feature_1` into `master`, you will have to first revert the revert commit that came along with the merge into master (so, you'd have to revert the `R` commit).

```
P--o--o--o--o--o--o---F2--R'-F1   master
\\                    /     /
 \\                  /     /
  \\                /     /
   \A--E---M---o--R/     /        feature_2
    \       \           /
     \B--C---D--o--o--o/          feature_1
```

Comment: This is one of the possible solutions I was thinking about myself. I had a command like this, to revert all merge commits from `feature_2`: `git rev-list --ancestry-path master..HEAD --merges | xargs -n 1 git revert --no-edit -m 1`. But I am not quite sure if I have to do the **revert of the revert** on the `feature_1` branch, once I want to merge it back.

Comment: So you are telling me I should merge `feature_2` into master, than revert the merge, and than merge `feature_1`? I am not quite sure that this will work. What will happen if I than merge `feature_1` once it's done. Would the commits B, C and D still be there?

Comment: You've got the order wrong.  You should revert the merge on `feature_2` **first**.  Then, when that branch is ready to go, merge it into `master`.  When you're ready to merge `feature_1` in, you would have to then revert the revert before you merged (so the sequence of commits would be to revert the revert, then merge `feature_1` into `master`).  The commits `B, C, and D` will be there since they're still preserved in the commit history.

Comment: OK, so this solution will also work, if the developer merged more than once or also a third feature branch into `feature_2` what he actually did. Thanks for your answer, but I think for a "one false merge only", the solution from @kan is a little cleaner.

Comment: I usually shy away from `rebase` on public branches since it means everyone is going to have divergent branches, which is a bit of a pain to coordinate with a lot of developers.

Comment: That is true. But it easier to have a clean history every developer involved in this specific feature understands, than having some revert, probably only a few understand.